# nodes <node_name> is forbidden issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Aster auto repair started his job he removed all the nodes but couldn't create new ones due to the issue:

> nodes "<node_name>" is forbidden: node "<node_name>" is not allowed to set the following labels: beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready"

So, now auto repair is stuck. Nodes can't spin up.

> Log shows "system:node:<node_name>" as a principal email.
> permission: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.create"
> resource: "core/v1/nodes/<node_name>"

Any ideas on what is happening and how I can fix that?

I compared the broken cluster with healthy ones and couldn't find any difference so far.

Comment: Hello @Julessoulfly, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below troubleshooting steps to understand and resolve your issue :**

Check the logs to identify the root cause of the node auto-repair loop. You can access and run VMs via SSH.

1. `sudo journalctl --unit=kubelet.service --all --utc --boot > /tmp/kubelet.log`
2. `/var/log/cloud-init.log`
3. [sosreport](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/sosreport)
4. `sudo systemctl status kube-node-installation`
5. `sudo systemctl status kube-node-configuration`

Mostly because the **Nodepool version is outdated** or **Taints** may cause this issue, refer to the below solutions, which may help to resolve the issue.

**Solution 1 :**

Check your environment node pool is running an outdated version. So, only the node pool has been stuck in "auto-repair" mode. I would suggest you to manually [upgrade the node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster?_ga=2.16163318.-132653956.1645452799#upgrading-nodes) using the below command:

```
$ gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME   --node-pool=NODE_POOL_NAME
```

After upgrading you can check the status of the node pool upgrade using the below command:

```
$ gcloud beta container operations list
```

Check auto upgrade is disabled for the node pool. So, I would suggest you enable node auto-upgrade if it is currently disabled. To enable the  node auto-upgrade, please try to execute the following command:

```
$ gcloud container node-pools update NODE_POOL_NAME  --cluster CLUSTER_NAME  --zone COMPUTE_ZONE  --enable-autoupgrade
```

See [Auto-repairing nodes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair) for details.

**Solution 2 :**

**Taints may cause the nodes not being registered in the master** (The issue may be that taints must have a unique key and effect pair. Check if a `duplicate key error` occurs, you may be using 2 taints that both have the same key and effect).

Could you please do a test removing these taints to see if the nodes can be registered in the master?This will help isolate the problem. Here the key is  "`app.kubernetes.io/name`" and the effect is `PreferNoSchedule`.

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.upgrade) ResponseError: code=400, 
message=Operation operation-12345678-123134456-123-123-123 is currently upgrading cluster primary. 
Please wait and try again once it is done.

Comment: From operations list: failed waiting for node registration. Then auto repair starts, which fails with " 404 status code returned. Requested resource not found."

Comment: May be causing the no.scale.up issue.  Refer to this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146831/timed-out-waiting-for-cluster-initialization-auto-upgrade-of-nodes-fail-or-ru) and also check your cluster's networking and confirm if connectivity to the master is correct.

Comment: Check your firewall rule is denied and connection may be dropped, due to that node registration failed. you have to create a firewall rule to resolve your issue. Refer to [Adding firewall rules for specific use cases](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#add_firewall_rules) for details.

Comment: Checking but it  looks good so far.

Comment: Anyway. isn't the 403 telling us that it can reach somewhere?

Comment: Also check your [Service account permissions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#service-account-permissions) and official [Troubleshoot node registration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-node-registration#when-node-registration) for more details.

Comment: Re-authenticate to the Google Cloud CLI : run gcloud auth login . See [Troubleshooting error 4xx issues](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#error_404) for more details.